# How do I "select" a link using Javascript so enter visits it

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm sure this is a basic question, but I just cannot find the right words to ask the almighty search-engines. I'm using the word "selected" in quotes because I don't know the right term for it. I'm sure if I did the question would be readily answered already.

When you press  on most webpages, you are able to cycle through the links on the page such that when you press  the browser visits the link in question. This is what a selected link looks like in Firefox:

[image: A link in a browser that has a dashed border to signify it is selected]

I want to be able to do this automatically on page load, such that  immediately after load takes you to the link of my choosing, but any other shenanigans like inputting in an input field cancels this behavior. I've looked through the DOM browser and can see nothing jumping out differentiates "This is a link" from other links on this page.

Comment: It is called _focus_ and you can have only one element _focused_. As soon as you click to an input your focus moves to it. That's why you can't have focused link while writing in an input at the same time.

Comment: It's hard to tell from your zoomed-in example, but how would you expect the user to know which link is being chosen if they are focused on the input box and they press enter? If your links have a visual state that you are maintaining in javascript that indicate which one is the last selected one, then you can choose it using a keypress event for your input.

Comment: @Jax-p focus looks to be what I want. If you write that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @lurker The point is that I don't want anything focused if you're typing in an input box. These should be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Then I refer back to the question in my prior comment. From the user's perspective, what should they expect?

Comment: @lurker This is for a search result. It actually used to be how Google rolled a little while ago. You searched for something, hit enter twice and it took you to the first link in the results table.

Comment: In that case, pressing enter in the search box had one specific function which could be programmed for the enter key pressing event. In your case, which perhaps I misunderstood, the action is taken by pressing enter depends upon some other selection.

Comment: This isn't an SPA. The enter on the search box reloads the page. Jax-p's answer is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called **focus** and you can have only one element *focused*. As soon as you click to an input your *focus* moves to it. That's why you can't have *focused* link while writing in an input at the same time.

> Focus determines where keyboard events go in the page at any given moment.

Source & you can read more at: [Introduction to Focus  |  Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/focus)